# elastic search embedded script optimization

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to simplify and optimize the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "range": {
              "ts": {
                "gte": "2014-12-18",
                "lte": "2014-12-18"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "track_events.event": "render"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "per_type": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "type",
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        },
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "per_hour": {
          "terms": {
            "script": "(doc[\"track_events.ts\"].value - doc[\"ts\"].value)/(1000 * 3600)",
            "order": {
              "_count": "desc"
            },
            "size": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The index in elasticsearch contains documents with fields `track_events.ts` and `ts`. The purpose is to count how many occurances exist in the hourly intervals between `track_events.ts` and `ts`. 
Example response:

```
                "buckets": [{
                    "key": "0",
                    "doc_count": 67736997
                },
                {
                    "key": "1",
                    "doc_count": 7193214
                },
                {
                    "key": "2",
                    "doc_count": 3406966
                },
                {
                    "key": "3",
                    "doc_count": 1988135
                }]
            }
```

which means that `67736997` counts where found that have time difference less than 1 hour, `7193214` counts with time difference less than 2 hours, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest performance gain would be to replace the script.

i.e. instead of doing:

```
(doc[\"track_events.ts\"].value - doc[\"ts\"].value)/(1000 * 3600)
```

pre-calculate this value when loading the data into Elasticsearch and put it into another field.  Then do the term aggregation on this field instead.